# Failed to find leader for Set([topic,0]) with Kafka-Spark Integration

Tags: apache-spark, ssl, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to use **SSL** for the Kafka-Spark integration. I have tested **Kafka** with SSL enabled and it works completely fine with sample consumer and producer.

Also, I have tried the integration of ***Spark - Kafka*** which also works without an issue when done *without* SSL in the spark-job.

Now, when I enable **SSL** in the **spark-job** I am getting an exception and the integration does not work.

The **ONLY** change I did to enable **SSL** in the **spark-job** is include the following lines of code in my job:

```java
    sparkConf.set("security.protocol", "SSL");
    sparkConf.set("ssl.truststore.location", "PATH/truststore.jks");
    sparkConf.set("ssl.truststore.password", "passwrd");
    sparkConf.set("ssl.keystore.location", "PATH/keystore.jks");
    sparkConf.set("ssl.keystore.password", "kstore");
    sparkConf.set("ssl.key.password", "keypass");
```

And this **sparkConf** is passed when creating the streaming context.

```java
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(10000));
```

And when I run the *job* the error I get is as follows:

```java
17/05/24 18:16:39 WARN ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread: [test-consumer-group_bmj-cluster-1495664195784-5f49cbd0-leader-finder-thread], Failed to find leader for Set([bell,0])
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.formatAddress(Utils.java:312)
    at kafka.cluster.Broker.connectionString(Broker.scala:62)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$$anonfun$fetchTopicMetadata$5.apply(ClientUtils.scala:89)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$$anonfun$fetchTopicMetadata$5.apply(ClientUtils.scala:89)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:89)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:60)
```

***Kafka Version** - 2.11-0.10.2.0*
***Spark Version** - 2.1.0*
***Scala Version** - 2.11.8*

*Streaming Libraries*

```xml
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help with regards to overcoming this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some digging in I was able to figure out the issue I had.

First of all, in order to enable SSL the SSL related, **kafka-params** need to passed into the ***KafkaUtils.createDirectStream()*** method and **NOT** the *sparkConf* of the *JavaStreamingContext*.

Then, the given *SSL parameters*:

> ```
> "security.protocol", "SSL"
> "ssl.truststore.location", "PATH/truststore.jks"
> "ssl.truststore.password", "passwrd"
> "ssl.keystore.location", "PATH/keystore.jks"
> "ssl.keystore.password", "kstore"
> "ssl.key.password", "keypass"
> ```

are not supported by the *spark-kafka-streaming* version "0-**8**_2.11", which I was using, hence I had to change this to version "0-**10**_2.11".

This in return has a complete API change of the method: **KafkaUtils.createDirectStream()** which is used to connect to Kafka.

An explanation is given in the documentation as to how to use it [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html).

So my final code snippet to connect to Kafka looks like this:

```java
final JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream =
            KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                    javaStreamingContext,
                    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                    ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topicsCollection, kafkaParams)
            );
```

with **kafka-params** being a map that holds all the SSL parameters.

Thanks
Shabir